# XAML ContentControl Data Binding is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contentcontrol, datatemplateselector

I have an issue with DataTemplates en ContentControl. My case is very specific.

XAML page:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Questionnaires.QuestionPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Questionnaires"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:selectors="using:Questionnaires.TemplateSelectors"
    xmlns:interop="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Interop"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
        <selectors:QuestionTypeItemTemplateSelector x:Key="QuestionTypeSelector" />
        <selectors:AnswerTypeItemTemplateSelector x:Key="AnswerTypeSelector"/>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="SingleSelectQuestionItemTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="10">
                <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                             IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Width="600" Height="Auto" GroupName="groupName">
                    <RadioButton.Content>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </RadioButton.Content>
                </RadioButton>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FreeQuestionItemTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="10">

                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource AnswerTypeSelector}" />


                <!--
                <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionMode="None">

                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </GridView>
                -->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MultiSelectQuestionItemTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="10">
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="600">
                    <CheckBox.Content>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </CheckBox.Content>    
                </CheckBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="LabelAnswerItemTemplate">
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextAreaAnswerItemTemplate">
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextFieldAnswerItemTemplate">
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="DateAnswerItemTemplate">
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="SliderAnswerItemTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="10">
                <Slider Width="600" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="25" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="Assets/IS_Bol_White.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="108*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="235*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1011*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{Binding Path=Assignment.Definition.Name}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                        IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,30,40" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="48"/>

        <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,30,0" Width="252" Height="71" Source="ms-appx:///Assets\innovationstudio.png" />

        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3,0,358,0" Width="650">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ProgressBar Grid.Row ="0" Maximum="1" Value="{Binding Progress}" IsIndeterminate="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Foreground="Black"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10 20" TextAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}"
                       Text="{Binding CurrentQuestion.Text}" />

        </Grid>

        <GridView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentQuestion.PossibleAnswers}" 
                  ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource QuestionTypeSelector}" SelectionMode="None">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>

        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Margin="3,0,358,0" Width="650">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="btn_Previous" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Vorige" Height="59" Width="175" IsEnabled="{Binding IsPreviousButtonEnabled}" Click="btnPrevious_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_Next" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Volgende" Height="59" Width="175" IsEnabled="{Binding IsNextButtonEnabled}" Click="btnNext_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I use an ItemTemplateSelector to specify which type of Question it's going to be. The QuestionType is definded in the PossibleAnswer object. My ItemTemplateSelector looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Questionnaires.Models;
using Questionnaires.ViewModels;

namespace Questionnaires.TemplateSelectors
{
    public class QuestionTypeItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            switch (((PossibleAnswer)(item)).QuestionType)
            {
                case "FREE":
                    return
                        ((Page) ((Frame) Window.Current.Content).Content).Resources["FreeQuestionItemTemplate"] 
                            as
                            Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
                case "SINGLE_SELECT":
                    return
                        ((Page) ((Frame) Window.Current.Content).Content).Resources["SingleSelectQuestionItemTemplate"]
                            as
                            Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
                case "MULTI_SELECT":
                    return
                        ((Page) ((Frame) Window.Current.Content).Content).Resources["MultiSelectQuestionItemTemplate"]
                            as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
                case "DROPDOWN":
                    return
                        ((Page) ((Frame) Window.Current.Content).Content).Resources["DropdownQuestionItemTemplate"]
                            as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way I specify which datatemplate needs to be shown on my page. I'm currently working on the FREE questions, so i'm talking specifically about one template now. The template on my xaml looks like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!-- TODO: Delete this line if the key AppName is declared in App.xaml -->
    <selectors:QuestionTypeItemTemplateSelector x:Key="QuestionTypeSelector" />
    <selectors:AnswerTypeItemTemplateSelector x:Key="AnswerTypeSelector"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="FreeQuestionItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="10">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource AnswerTypeSelector}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SliderAnswerItemTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="10">
            <Slider Width="600" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="25" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

To make things a little clearer: there is a difference between QuestionType and PossibleAnswerType.
QuestionType can be :

FREE 
SINGLE_SELECT 
MULTI_SELECT 
DROPDOWN
TABLE

PossibleAnswerType can be :

LABEL
TEXT_AREA
TEXT_FIELD
DATE
SLIDER

I try to get the PossibleAnswerType of my PossibleAnswer in the FreeQuestionTemplate.
I'm using the ContentControl to do this, but the binding of my PossibleAnswer doesn't seem to work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Questionnaires.Models;

namespace Questionnaires.TemplateSelectors
{
    public class AnswerTypeItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            switch (((PossibleAnswer) (item)).PossibleAnswerType)
            {
                case "LABEL":
                    return
                       ((Page)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content).Resources["LabelAnswerItemTemplate"]
                           as
                           Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
                case "TEXT_AREA":
                    return
                       ((Page)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content).Resources["TextAreaAnswerItemTemplate"]
                           as
                           Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
                case "TEXT_FIELD":
                    return
                       ((Page)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content).Resources["TextFieldAnswerItemTemplate"]
                           as
                           Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
                case "DATE":
                    return
                       ((Page)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content).Resources["DateAnswerItemTemplate"]
                           as
                           Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
                case "SLIDER":
                    return
                       ((Page)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content).Resources["SliderAnswerItemTemplate"]
                           as
                           Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my AnswerTypeItemTemplateSelector, the item object is always null. Anyone got me some suggestions on how to do this?

Kind regards!

Comment: Try reading over your question *before* you post it next time... you were missing a chunk of code. I've reformatted it so it can be seen now.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `null` check? `if (object == null) return;`

Comment: The thing is that my item should be a PossibleAnswer :) The null check doesn't matter here. The item should contain data at this point.

Comment: Are you saying that it is *always* `null`?

Comment: At this moment it is. But this is not how it should be. That object "item" should be a PossibleAnswer. But I guess that the binding is wrong or invalid somewhere.

Comment: Ok, so now I finally understand your problem. :) Can you please show your XAML for how you have set your `DataContext` for the page and where you are using the `FreeQuestionItemTemplate`?

Comment: I have put the complete xaml in my question :) Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looking over your new code, I think that I've worked out what your problem is. Your `AnswerTypeItemTemplateSelector` is used in your `FreeQuestionItemTemplate DataTemplate`, which is used in your `QuestionTypeItemTemplateSelector`. Unless you've left out some XAML, it seems as though you aren't using your `QuestionTypeItemTemplateSelector` anywhere, so none of this is 'plugged in'.

---

UPDATE >>>

In order for any `Binding` to work, you *must* set the `DataContext` of your `Page` to some meaningful value. The `DataContext` tells the elements in the UI where to look for its data bound values. Without setting a `DataContext`, the UI elements will have no access to any data (unless some has been declared in XAML, but let's not confuse matters with this). Please take a look at the [DataContext in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF) article on CodeProject for more information.

Comment: I'm using my QuestionTypeItemTemplateSelector in my gridview at the bottom of my xaml: ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource QuestionTypeSelector}"

Comment: Ah... so you are... I was searching for `QuestionTypeItemTemplateSelector` instead... I'll take another look. You never responded to my question about your `DataContext`... I don't see you setting it anywhere. Please show how you have set this essential property.

Comment: You mean that I have to set the DataContext on the ContentPresenter? Or on which tag should it be?

Comment: Ok so I have changed my ContentPresenter to this:

<ContentPresenter ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource AnswerTypeSelector}" DataContext="{Binding}" />

But I still get a "null" for the item object in my AnswerTypeSelector.